# Проверка наличия ключа в Бд Firebase

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-database

Делаю проверку таким образом

```
If(reference.child(userId).getKey() == null){
   //...
}
```

В итоге получаю False, но такого ключа у меня нет. Я уже понял что делаю что то не верно, прошу наставить на верный путь.

Мне нужно узнать существует такой ключ в моей БД или нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать другой метод

```
 referens.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.child(userId).exists()) {
                // run some code
            }else{

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```